# Why are all angels masculine?

Tags: angels, spirit

Nowhere in the Bible are angels feminine.  If angels are messengers from God, why do these messengers always manifest themselves as masculine?  Is it because they assume the gender of their Divine dispatcher?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, angels are different beings from us as they do not procreate. Matthew 22:29,30 says:

> Jesus replied, “You are in error because you do not know the Scriptures or the power of
>       God. At the resurrection people will neither marry nor be given in marriage; they will be
>       like the angels in heaven.

Because they do not procreate, gender really is irrelevant.

EDIT: I will add; I believe that in the Bible they take the shape of a man, but as in human shape. We know not if this is a female or male shape. Just like in the Garden of Eden:

> So God created **man** in his own image, in the image of God created he him; **male and
>       female** created he them.

So man can be used to refer to mankind, instead of just male.

Comment: Then why do angels manifest as masculine?  I agree angels do not procreate, but if gender is irrelevant then why do angels present themselves in male form?

Comment: Well actually I believe the context here is life after the resurrection at the last day, but just because the context is different, does not mean it does not give us an insight into the mystery that is the angelic host. It is a good question though.

Comment: You know you are correct insight when handled correctly is beneficial and you are handling scripture correctly.

Comment: Agreed. I believe I did not take it out of context. I believe I just took Jesus' words as He meant them. But if I did, will you please show me?

Comment: What about the question:"is it because they assume the gender of their Divine dispatcher"?

Comment: Genesis 6 could imply that angels DID procreate.

Comment: No. I think what Jesus said makes it clear that they do not. Genesis 6 is not talking about angels it is talking about men. Sons of God refers to people that obeyed the LORD, the descendants of Seth. The daughters of men were the descendants of Cain, which did not follow in the way of the LORD. Verse 1 and 3 makes it clear that it is talking about man, that is humans.

Comment: @Rick I'm not sure about this. God is a Spirit as are angels so maybe your assumption is correct. But it is not a Biblical foundation, at this point we are only assuming as this is all that is known.

Comment: @jlaverde sounds like a good question for hermeneutics.

Comment: @jlaverde, Your example: "God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female" assumes the word "man" as mankind, many would not agree.  The Hebrew word "Adam" here is rendered as man.  So the Hebrew text would read "So God created Adam in the image of God...male and female"

Comment: @Rick I disagree. The text clearly makes a difference between man and male. The Hebrew word Adam could mean first man or Adam, but it could also mean human being. How do we know which it is? The rest of the text tells us, male(zakar) and female created He them. 'Them' who? Man(adam), humanity. It doesn't make sense to say God created the male sex and created it male and female, it is talking about mankind, humans.

Comment: @jlaverde, What you assume is that you know precisely what Adam was before Eve was taken from him.

Comment: I'm not sure how you arrived at that conclusion. "So God created 'mankind' in his own image, in the image of God he created them; male and female he created them." NIV  Now let's try what you're saying. "So God created Adam in his own image, in the image of God he created them; male and female he created them." Obviously this does NOT make sense as it would be referring to Adam as them, and also referring to Adam as male and female. The word 'adam' here is clearly 'mankind' as used in the NIV.

Comment: @Clearly that is your opinion.

Comment: Clearly, you're not paying attention to the text.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts I have had  over the years:

```
God created man in his own image, but God is not material and so He may have
used the design which he used to form the Angels as a blueprint for making man.

His original creation was masculine (Adam) for which he may have used the Angels 
as a pattern.

So then Man may have been created in God's image (body, Spirit and Soul) which has
no Material form and in the pattern of the Angels.

And then when He decided to create woman as a companion for man; Knowing all things
and especially that woman would be deceived by Satan and then entice Adam to
intentionally sin, and that her punishment was to be the bearing of children
modified that pattern and created Eve.
```

Of  course that is pure conjecture on my part and there are no Scriptures for me to cite, but there are some things that I believe God just didn't think we needed to know before we go to Glory.